# MongoMapper two one-to-many relationships on one model

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra, mongomapper

I am trying to model a question/answer system similar to StackOverflow's in that there is a Question, it has Answers and the Question and Answer both belong to different users (but the Answer also belongs to the Question) My code is below:

```
class User
    include MongoMapper::Document

    many :questions

    timestamps!
end

class Question
    include MongoMapper::Document

    belongs_to :user

    many :answers
    many :comments

    timestamps!
end

class Answer
    include MongoMapper::Document

    belongs_to :question

    many :comments

    timestamps!
end
```

I have a couple of questions:

1. How can I have two things have a relationship with the one model? A Question can have many Answers and a user can have many Answers.
2. if I create an answer with `question.answers.create()` how do I associate the user with it? can I set a `user_id` manually or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself - I don't quite understand what lead me to believe that I can't just have multiple relationships. How closed minded of me!

For anyone else who is stuck:

```
class User
    include MongoMapper::Document

    many :questions
    many :answers

    timestamps!
end

class Question
    include MongoMapper::Document

    belongs_to :user

    many :answers
    many :comments

    timestamps!
end

class Answer
    include MongoMapper::Document

    belongs_to :question
    belongs_to :user

    many :comments

    timestamps!
end
```

create new 'answers' like so:

```
q = Question.find(id)
u = User.find(id)
a = q.answers.create(
    :user_id => u._id
)
```